# node.js Passport Wrapper 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport

First attempt was done [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36938/node-js-passport-wrapper):

My second attempt (now using jslint to make sure the spacing is correct and have incorporate the majority of the feedback from previous attempt).

```
/*
 * Export single function that creates the passportControl object
 * The function has two parameters:
 *      app:            The nodejs/express service object.
 *                      This is used to register the end points
 *                      this authentication object listens too.
 *      register:       See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36940/local-user-registration
 *                      For an example implementation. This is still being worked on.
 *
 *      It also uses an external module for configuration (ie holding all the secrets)
 *      This file is not in source control (but in a key repository nice and safe).
 *      config: Expected fields:
 *                  config.app              The URL of the site.
 *                  config.passport         An object containing the secrets for each service
 *                                          The values will depend on the service and the
 *                                          implementation of passport-<service> module
 *                                          See the passport code for more detail
 *                  Example:
 *                      passport: {
 *                          facebook: {
 *                              clientID:       'FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID',
 *                              clientSecret:   'FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET',
 *                          },
 *                          twitter:  {
 *                              consumerKey:    'TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY',
 *                              consumerSecret: 'TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET',
 *                          }
 *                      }
 *
 *      The passport control object is supposed to be a wrapper for
 *      nodejs/express/passport authentication.
 *
 *      When the object is created it adds three end points to the server for authentication
 *      /api/auth?type=<AuthenticationType>
 *      /api/auth/callback?type=<AuthenticationType>
 *      /api/authexit
 *
 *          Where AuthenticationType is the service doing the authentication.
 *              Eg Facebook/Twitter/Amazon etc
 *
 *      A fourth end point is added to get display info about the user:
 *      And information about supported authentication services. This allows the
 *      front-end to display the appropriate controls without needing code changes.
 *      /api/userInfo
 *
 *      This end point returns the following json object:
 *      {
 *          logedin:        true if the user is currently logged in; false otherwise.
 *          displayName:    The users display name if logged in, '' otherwise
 *          loginMethods:   A list of services that can be used to login if not logged in.
 *      }
 *
 * This object has two public methods:
 *      checkPassport(req, res)
 *      registerUser(req, res)
 *
 *          req:        http request received from node.
 *          res:        response object we use to reply to the request.
 *
 * These are automatically hooked up to the exposed endpoints.
 * To extend this for any particular service just add the appropriate
 * objects to the array built with buildData()
 *
 */

// Global object for correctly escaping URL
var querystring = require('querystring');
var config      = require('../config.js');

// Private Method
function addStandardStratergy(passport, register, result, name, prittyName, type, app, config) {

    config.callbackURL  = 'http://' + app + '/api/auth/callback?type=' + name;
    console.log('Callback: ' + config.callbackURL);

    var Strategy    = require(type).Strategy;
    /*jslint unparam: true*/
    passport.use(new Strategy(config,
        function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            register.updateUser({
                provider:    profile.provider,
                providerId:  profile.id,
                displayName: profile.displayName
            },
                function(err, localUser) {
                    if (err) {done(err); return; }
                    done(null, localUser);
                });
        }));
    result.auth[name]       = passport.authenticate(name);
    result.callback[name]   = function(req, res, page) {passport.authenticate(name, { successRedirect: page, failureRedirect: '/login'})(req, res); };
    result.services.push({type: name, display: prittyName});
    /*jslint unparam: false*/
}

/*
 * This builds the data object central to 'passportControl'
 * The Key: Is the name of the 'AuthenticationType' the value is the passport object that does the authentication.
 * auth:        Handles the initial authentication request.
 * callback:    Handles the callback from the authentication service
 * services:    A list of social services that can be used for logging in
 */
function buildData(passport, register) {

    // Add more strategies as required here.
    /*jslint unparam: true*/
    var result = {
        auth: {
            default:    function(req, res) {res.redirect('/login?' + querystring.stringify({reg_error: 'Invalid Authentication Type (attempt)'})); }
        },
        callback: {
            default:    function(req, res) {res.redirect('/login?' + querystring.stringify({reg_error: 'Invalid Authentication Type (callback)'})); }
        },
        services: []
    };
    /*jslint unparam: false*/

    /*
     * Add a call for each social network you want to use for registration
     */
    addStandardStratergy(passport, register, result, 'facebook', 'Facebook', 'passport-facebook', config.app, config.passport.facebook);
    addStandardStratergy(passport, register, result, 'twitter', 'Twitter', 'passport-twitter',  config.app, config.passport.twitter);

    return result;
}

module.exports = function(app, register) {

    // App:         Application object
    // register:    The user registration service
    //              This has been abstracted from the passport authentication code.
    //              I will document this interface separately.


    // Get the passport object we reap
    // Correctly initialize and turn on sessions.
    var passport, passportControl;
    passport = require('passport');
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    // Set passport to only save the user ID to the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(localUser, done) {
        done(null, localUser.id);
    });

    // Set passport to retrieve the user object using the
    // saved id (see serializeUser).
    passport.deserializeUser(function(localUserId, done) {
        register.getSavedUser(localUserId,  function(err, localUser) {
            if (err) { done(err); return; }
            done(null, localUser);
        });
    });

    // Create the passport control object
    passportControl =  {
        data:           buildData(passport, register),
        checkPassport: function(req, res) {
            req.session.page  = req.query.page || '/';
            return this.performAction(this.data.auth, req, res);
        },
        registerUser: function(req, res) {
            req.query.page    = req.session.page;
            return this.performAction(this.data.callback, req, res);
        },
        deAuthorize: function(req, res) {
            var page  = req.query.page || '/';
            req.logout();
            res.redirect(page);
        },
        performAction: function (dataItem, req, res) {
            var action, page;
            action  = dataItem[req.query.type];
            page  = req.query.page || '/';
            if (action === null) {
                action = dataItem['default'];
            }
            return action(req, res, page);
        },
        authTypes: function() {
            return this.data.services;
        }
    };
    // The service endpoints
    // This will control all authentication.
    app.get('/api/authexit',        function(req, res) { passportControl.deAuthorize(req, res); });
    app.get('/api/auth',            function(req, res) { passportControl.checkPassport(req, res); });
    app.get('/api/auth/callback',   function(req, res) { passportControl.registerUser(req, res); });
    app.get('/api/userInfo',        function(req, res) {
        res.json({
            logedin:        req.user ? true : false,
            displayName:    req.user ? req.user.displayName : '',
            loginMethods:   req.user ? [] : passportControl.authTypes()
        });
    });

    return passportControl;
};
```

### Usage in a node.js application:

#### Edit `buildData()`

Add appropriate calls to `addStandardStratergy()` (see examples provided)

#### Call In your code like this.

```
var express     = require('express');
var ppControl   = require('./PassportControl.js');


var app          = express();
var register     = /* Your object for persisting user info */;
var customsAgent = ppControl(app, register);
```

#### Done.

### HTML on the client end to display login controls

Note: using Angular to do the work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![[CDATA[*/

function LoginController($scope) {

    $scope.logins   = [];

    $scope.doLogin = function(type) {
        window.location.href    = '/api/auth?type=' + type + '&page=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL);
    };

    /*jslint unparam: true*/
    /* Notice the call here to get the button info */
    $.get(
        '/api/userInfo',
        '',
        function(data, textStatus, request) {
            if (request.status === 200) {
                $scope.logins   = data.loginMethods;
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        },
        "json"
    );
    /*jslint unparam: false*/
}

/*]]>*/
</script>

<!-- fa           Generic button using icon
     fa-facebook  places facebook icon on button
     fa-twitter   places twitter  con on button 
     fa- ...      etc
-->
<div ng-controller="LoginController">
    <!-- Other parts of control removed -->
    <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <button ng-repeat="login in logins" ng-click="doLogin(login.type)">
            <i class="fa fa-{{login.type}}"></i> | Login with {{login.display}}
         </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `addStandardStratergy` ;) In all seriousness, this code looks very nice.

Comment: Somehow ended up checking your resume. There is a spelling mistake. Javascrip

Comment: @AseemBansal: Which resume (can you provide a link)? I don't think there is javascript on my resume since I don't do it much.

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/lokiastar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really like this code, I only have a few minor observations:

- `'http://'` <- https should be an option without modifying your wrapper ?
- `(request.status === 200)` <- You should provide support for when things go wrong ? Also I think `success` is only called when `request.status` is `200`
- The fact that `result.auth.default` and `result.auth.callback` are so similar bugs me (DRY), but I could not find a neater way to do it
- Spelling: `logedin` -> `loggedIn`

Other than that, very cool, something I would consider using for my own Node projects.

Comment: Watch out this weekend. I have an update to this code that supports 12 popular sites out of the box. Facebook/Twitter/Google+/FourSquare/LinkedIn/GitHub/Meetup/AOL/Yahoo/Vimeo/Instagram/Tumbler. (Note I did not write any of the actual code I just add glue to plug the already written code (which seems to be this guy https://github.com/jaredhanson?tab=repositories)

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/47392/507