# node.js Passport Wrapper 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport

First attempt was done [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/36938/507)
Second attempt was done [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/40159/507)

#### Huge comment at top

```
/*
 * Export single function that creates the passportControl object
 * The function has two parameters:
 *      app:            The nodejs/express service object.
 *                      This is used to register the end points
 *                      this authentication object listens too.
 *      register:       An object that abstracts user registrations it
 *                      must support the following methods:
 *                          updateUser({<user object>})
 *                          getSavedUser(localUserId,  function(err, localUser) {})
 *
 *      It also uses an external module for configuration (ie holding all the secrets)
 *      This file is not in source control (but in a key repository nice and safe).
 *      config: Expected fields:
 *                  config.app              The URL of the site.
 *                  config.passport         An object containing the secrets for each service
 *                                          The values will depend on the service and the
 *                                          implementation of passport-<service> module
 *                                          See the passport code for more detail
 *                  Example:
 *
                    {
                        app:    'iPubCrawlMaps.com',
                        short:  'iPCM',
                        passport: {
                            facebook: {
                                clientID:       '<My FaceBook Client>'
                                clientSecret:   '<My FaceBool Secret>'
                            },
                            twitter:  {
                                consumerKey:    '<My Twitter Key>',
                                consumerSecret: '<My Twitter Secret>'
                            },
                            google: {
                                returnURL:      'http://<My Site>/api/auth/callback?type=google',
                                realm:          'http://<My Site>/'
                            },
                            foursquare: {
                                clientID:       '<My FourSquare ID>',
                                clientSecret:   '<My FourSquare Secret>'
                            },
                            linkedin: {
                                consumerKey:    '<My LinkedIn Key>',
                                consumerSecret: '<My LinkedIn Secret>'
                            },
                            github: {
                                clientID:       '<My GitHub ID>',
                                clientSecret:   '<My GitHub Secret>'
                            },
                            meetup: {
                                consumerKey:    '<My Meetup Key>',
                                consumerSecret: '<My Meetup Secret>'
                            },
                            aol: {
                                returnURL:      'http://<My Site>/api/auth/callback?type=aol',
                                realm:          'http://<My Site>/'
                            },
                            yahoo: {
                                returnURL:      'http://<My Site>/api/auth/callback?type=yahoo',
                                realm:          'http://<My Site>/'
                            vimeo: {
                                consumerKey:    '<My Vimeo Key>',
                                consumerSecret: '<My Vimeo Secret>'
                            },
                            instagram: {
                                clientID:       '<My Instagram ID>',
                                clientSecret:   '<My Instagram Secret>'
                            },
                            tumblr: {
                                consumerKey:    '<My Tumbler Key>',
                                consumerSecret: '<My Tumbler Secret>'
                            }
                        }
                    };

 *
 *      The passport control object is supposed to be a wrapper for
 *      nodejs/express/passport authentication.
 *
 *      When the object is created it adds three end points to the server for authentication
 *      /api/auth?type=<AuthenticationType>
 *      /api/auth/callback?type=<AuthenticationType>
 *      /api/authexit
 *
 *          Where AuthenticationType is the service doing the authentication.
 *              Eg Facebook/Twitter/Amazon etc
 *
 *      A fourth end point is added to get display info about the user:
 *      And information about supported authentication services. This allows the
 *      front-end to display the appropriate controls without needing code changes.
 *      /api/userInfo
 *
 *      This end point returns the following json object:
 *      {
 *          logedin:        true if the user is currently logged in; false otherwise.
 *          displayName:    The users display name if logged in, '' otherwise
 *          loginMethods:   A list of services that can be used to login if not logged in.
 *      }
 *
 * This object has two public methods:
 *      checkPassport(req, res)
 *      registerUser(req, res)
 *
 *          req:        http request received from node.
 *          res:        response object we use to reply to the request.
 *
 * These are automatically hooked up to the exposed endpoints.
 * To extend this for any particular service just add the appropriate
 * objects to the array built with buildData()
 *
 */
```

#### Global Config I use

```
// Global object for correctly escaping URL
var querystring = require('querystring');
var config      = require('../config.js');
```

#### The call to Register a user

```
function registerUser(register, provider, providerId, displayName, done) {
    register.updateUser({
        provider:    provider,
        providerId:  providerId,
        displayName: displayName
    },
        function(err, localUser) {
            if (err) {done(err); return; }
            done(null, localUser);
        }
        );
}
```

#### The heart. A standard function for registering a login stratergy

```
function addStandardStratergy(stratergyConfig, name, prittyName, type, typeName, config, loginAction) {

    config.callbackURL  = 'http://' + stratergyConfig.app + '/api/auth/callback?type=' + name;

    var Strategy    = require(type).Strategy;
    stratergyConfig.passport.use(new Strategy(config, loginAction));
    stratergyConfig.result.auth[name]       = stratergyConfig.passport.authenticate(name);
    stratergyConfig.result.callback[name]   = function(req, res, page) {stratergyConfig.passport.authenticate(name, { successRedirect: page, failureRedirect: '/login'})(req, res); };
    stratergyConfig.result.services.push({type: name, classInfo: typeName, display: prittyName});
}
```

#### Build the data. Basically calls addStandardStratergy() with custom param for each site.

```
/*
 * This builds the data object central to 'passportControl'
 * The Key: Is the name of the 'AuthenticationType' the value is the passport object that does the authentication.
 * auth:        Handles the initial authentication request.
 * callback:    Handles the callback from the authentication service
 * services:    A list of social services that can be used for logging in
 */
function buildData(passport, register) {

    // Add more strategies as required here.
    var result, stratergyConfig, useDisplayName, useUserName, buildName, OAuthGetLoginAction, OpenIdLoginAction;
    result = {
        auth: {
            default:    function(req, res) {res.redirect('/login?' + querystring.stringify({reg_error: 'Invalid Authentication Type (attempt)'})); }
        },
        callback: {
            default:    function(req, res) {res.redirect('/login?' + querystring.stringify({reg_error: 'Invalid Authentication Type (callback)'})); }
        },
        services: []
    };

    /*
     * Add a call for each social network you want to use for registration
     */

    stratergyConfig = {
        passport:       passport,
        result:         result,
        app:            config.app
    };
    /*
     * I only use these services to log people in to associate them to an account.
     * Each of the services I use provides varying information. All I want is a display name.
     * But each service provides a different set of attributes. So I use the following functions
     * in association with addStandardStratergy() to pull the "Display Name" from the returned data.
     */
    useDisplayName = function(profile) {return profile.displayName || 'anonymous'; };
    useUserName    = function(profile) {return profile.username || 'ananymous'; };
    buildName      = function(profile) {return profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName; };


    /*
     * Two major authentication methods are used by these sites:
     *      OAuth
     *      OpenID
     *
     * A method for handling each type of authentication.
     */
    OAuthGetLoginAction = function (name, getDisplayName) {
        return function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            registerUser(register, profile.provider, profile.id, getDisplayName(profile), done);
        };
    };
    OpenIdLoginAction = function OpenIdLoginAction(name) {
        return function(identifier, profile, done) {
            registerUser(register, name, identifier, useDisplayName(profile), done);
        };
    };


    /*
     * Register the different services you want to use here.
     * The authentication information is the 5th paramaeter and pulled from the config info
     * described in the main comment above
     */
    //                                    name          prittyName  type                    typeName        config                      loginAction
    //      Name:           Used internally and for callbacks.
    //      prittyName:     Displayed to the user in any API
    //      typeName:       Used for CSS typing in the display.
    //      config:         Object that holds config information for passport.
    //      loginAction:    Function called on successful login to retrieve specific user info (I just get Display name).

    addStandardStratergy(stratergyConfig, 'facebook',   'Facebook', 'passport-facebook',    'facebook',     config.passport.facebook,   OAuthGetLoginAction('facebook', useDisplayName));
    addStandardStratergy(stratergyConfig, 'twitter',    'Twitter',  'passport-twitter',     'twitter',      config.passport.twitter,    OAuthGetLoginAction('twitter', useDisplayName));
    addStandardStratergy(stratergyConfig, 'google',     'Google+',  'passport-google',      'google-plus',  config.passport.google,     OpenIdLoginAction('google'));
    addStandardStratergy(stratergyConfig, 'foursquare', 'Foursquare','passport-foursquare', 'foursquare',   config.passport.foursquare, OAuthGetLoginAction('foursquare', buildName));
    addStandardStratergy(stratergyConfig, 'linkedin',   'Linkedin', 'passport-linkedin',    'linkedin',     config.passport.linkedin,   OAuthGetLoginAction('linkedin', useDisplayName));
    addStandardStratergy(stratergyConfig, 'github',     'GitHub',   'passport-github',      'github',       config.passport.github,     OAuthGetLoginAction('github', useDisplayName));
    addStandardStratergy(stratergyConfig, 'meetup',     'Meetup',   'passport-meetup',      'meetup',       config.passport.meetup,     OAuthGetLoginAction('meetup', useDisplayName));
    addStandardStratergy(stratergyConfig, 'aol',        'AOL',      'passport-aol',         'aol',          config.passport.aol,        OpenIdLoginAction('aol'));
    addStandardStratergy(stratergyConfig, 'yahoo',      'Yahoo!',   'passport-yahoo',       'yahoo',        config.passport.yahoo,      OpenIdLoginAction('yahoo'));
    addStandardStratergy(stratergyConfig, 'vimeo',      'Vimeo',    'passport-vimeo',       'vimeo',        config.passport.vimeo,      OAuthGetLoginAction('vimeo', useDisplayName));
    addStandardStratergy(stratergyConfig, 'instagram',  'Instagram','passport-instagram',   'instagram',    config.passport.instagram,  OAuthGetLoginAction('instagram', useDisplayName));
    addStandardStratergy(stratergyConfig, 'tumblr',     'Tumblr',   'passport-tumblr',      'tumblr',       config.passport.tumblr,     OAuthGetLoginAction('tumblr', useUserName));

    return result;
}
```

#### The object we export back to the applicaiton.

See (second try for usage).

```
module.exports = function(app, register) {

    // App:         Application object
    // register:    The user registration service
    //              This has been abstracted from the passport authentication code.
    //              I will document this interface separately.


    // Get the passport object we reap
    // Correctly initialize and turn on sessions.
    var passport, passportControl;
    passport = require('passport');
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    // Set passport to only save the user ID to the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(localUser, done) {
        done(null, localUser.id);
    });

    // Set passport to retrieve the user object using the
    // saved id (see serializeUser).
    passport.deserializeUser(function(localUserId, done) {
        register.getSavedUser(localUserId,  function(err, localUser) {
            if (err) { done(err); return; }
            done(null, localUser);
        });
    });

    // Create the passport control object
    passportControl =  {
        data:           buildData(passport, register),
        checkPassport: function(req, res) {
            req.session.page  = req.query.page || '/';
            return this.performAction(this.data.auth, req, res);
        },
        registerUser: function(req, res) {
            req.query.page    = req.session.page;
            return this.performAction(this.data.callback, req, res);
        },
        deAuthorize: function(req, res) {
            var page  = req.query.page || '/';
            req.logout();
            res.redirect(page);
        },
        performAction: function (dataItem, req, res) {
            var action, page;
            action  = dataItem[req.query.type];
            page  = req.query.page || '/';
            if (action === null) {
                action = dataItem['default'];
            }
            return action(req, res, page);
        },
        authTypes: function() {
            return this.data.services;
        }
    };
    // The service endpoints
    // This will control all authentication.
    app.get('/api/authexit',        function(req, res) { passportControl.deAuthorize(req, res); });
    app.get('/api/auth',            function(req, res) { passportControl.checkPassport(req, res); });
    app.get('/api/auth/callback',   function(req, res) { passportControl.registerUser(req, res); });
    app.get('/api/userInfo',        function(req, res) {
        res.json({
            logedin:        req.user ? true : false,
            displayName:    req.user ? req.user.displayName : '',
            loginMethods:   req.user ? [] : passportControl.authTypes()
        });
    });

    return passportControl;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're nailing it.

As a nitpick, the indentation is a bit off in the `registerUser` function definition.

Another tiny thing in the same function, instead of this:

> ```
> function(err, localUser) {
>     if (err) {done(err); return; }
>     done(null, localUser);
> }
> ```

How about the shorter:

```
function(err, localUser) {
    err ? done(err) : done(null, localUser);
}
```

Since the method is not supposed to return anything anyway, this will have the same effect as the original, but it's shorter and perhaps a tiny bit easier to read.

Comment: The first time that I see a ternary not used for an assignment and thinking `I am okay with that`, +1 once I can vote again

Comment: the entire callback could be replaced by the `done` function. @konijn usually when you hit that piece of sugar is because your callback is not neccessary ;)

Comment: It depends on what is inside `done()`, `undefined` is not `null`, so just calling `done()` could have adverse side effects